# $.ajax never ending loop stop

Tags: ajax, infinite-loop

I have a html-document, in which I want to load a table from an extern html-file. In this file should be another load to the same file. When I start this, I get an enless loop.
Can anybody tell me how I can still end the loading after 10 times?

Ok, here is some of my code

html-document:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function table(){
    $.ajax({    
    url: "table.html",
         success: function(data) {$('#test1').html(data);},
    error: function(){alert('no!');},
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="Button" onclick="table();" value="KNOPF" id="knopf"/>
<p id="test1">TEST </p>
</body>
</html>
```

table

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({    
    url: "table.html",
         success: function(data) {
    $('#test1').html(data);},
    error: function(){alert('no!');},
    }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="test1"><p>
<table border="1">
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see what code you have so far?

Comment: What about showing us some code?

Answer (score 0):

It might be probably server-side redirecting/header redirecting. Check if you have some redirects in your script(s)